# Multiple Items selected of ListView when Click on Single Item of Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have multiple items in `ListView` and list of item is larger than the screen size.To view all items I scroll down to the `ListView`. `ListView` contain one `CheckBox` and Two `TextView`.

[image]

When I select first item of the `ListView` other item is Also selected which is down in Scroll(which is not showing on screen and will show after scrolling).
It work properly when I removed some items from the `ListView`. Remaining items fit on mobile screen.The problem comes only when scrolling is added.
I am stuck on that problem from yesterday.

```
 ListView lv=findViewById(R.id.listOfStudents);
 Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllData();
 final String[] columns = new String[]{CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CONTACT};
 int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.phone};
 dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.student_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);
 lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
         CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) listView.getAdapter().getView(position,view , null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
         if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
             checkBox.setChecked(false);
         } else {
             checkBox.setChecked(true);
         }
     }
 });
```

---

code for adapter. CountriesDbAdapter.java

```
package com.example.usmanasghar.studentattendancefromdatabase;

/**
 * Created by Usman Asghar on 09/02/2016.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

    public class CountriesDbAdapter {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEY_CONTACT = "contact";
        public static final String KEY_PRESENT = "Present";
        private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
        private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ClassRoom";
        private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "StudentInfo";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private final Context mCtx;

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                        KEY_NAME + "," +
                        KEY_CONTACT +
                        ");";


        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }

        public CountriesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
            this.mCtx = ctx;
        }

        public CountriesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() {
            if (mDbHelper != null) {
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
        }

        public long createCountry(String name,
                                  String contact) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            initialValues.put(KEY_CONTACT, contact);
            return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        public int deleteStudentWithId(String id) {
            int doneDelete;
            doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, "_id= ?", new String[]{id});//Delete from table where _id=?
            return doneDelete;
        }
       public Cursor fetchContactsWithId(String id){
           Cursor mCursor = null;
           if (id == null || id.length() == 0) {
               mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTACT},
                       null, null, null, null, null);
           } else {
               mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,KEY_CONTACT},
                       KEY_ROWID + " like '%" + id + "%'", null,
                       null, null, null, null);
           }
           if (mCursor != null) {
               mCursor.moveToFirst();
           }
           return mCursor;
        }
        public void UpdateData(String Name, String PhoneNumber, String id) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, Name);
            cv.put(KEY_CONTACT, PhoneNumber);
            mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, cv, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
        }

        public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
            Cursor mCursor = null;
            if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
                mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTACT},
                        null, null, null, null, null);
            } else {
                mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTACT},
                        KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                        null, null, null, null);
            }
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;

        }

        public Cursor fetchAllData() {
            Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTACT},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }
        public Cursor fetchOnlyContacts() {
            Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{ KEY_CONTACT},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }

        public void insertSomeCountries() {
            createCountry("Jordan", "03096759397");
            createCountry("Liza", "03094711934");
            createCountry("Johny", "03321625972");
            createCountry(Xeomia", "03088800088");
            createCountry("Shina", "03058825525");


        }

    }
```

Comment: The error in that line. CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) listView.getAdapter().getView(position,view , null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
It generates same id for two items.

Comment: please post your adapter code.

Comment: I add the code for adapter.

Comment: Try replacing `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) listView.getAdapter().getView(position,view , null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` with `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);`

Comment: it does not work. By using it, it check only one checkBox from ListView.if i click on other checkbox it uncheck the first checkbox and the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with CheckBox inside ListView is that the view gets recycled due to recycling of ListView and the value of Checkbox(check or uncheck) is not maintained. To, maintain the state to CheckBox there has to be something that can store the state of Checkbox.

**@Lalit Poptani** have written a blog for **[ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)**

Answer (score 0):

ListView used recycling of Views created earlier. When ListView created it's create the number of View plus one which can be show able on screen when you scroll the screen previous view get recycle by replacing content of it eg - when 5 rows are displaying on screen and you scroll down then first row of view content replace by 6 position row that's the reason another item get selected when you scrolling. You need to update data value of checkbox for perticular row not the checkbox of row.